# Add an image every 3 posts in Wordpress/Magento PHP loop

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add an image into my blog feed every three posts. I am using a wordpress integration extension for Magento by Fishpig.

This is the code I have to work with:

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
<div class="post-list">
    <ul id="post-list">
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <li class="item<?php if ($post->isSticky()): ?> featured is-sticky<?php endif; ?>    <?php echo $post->getPostFormat() ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getPostRenderer($post)->toHtml() ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

                </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList($('post-list'));</script>
    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple.

Just use below code:

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <div class="post-list">
        <ul id="post-list">
            <?php $count=0; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if ($post->isSticky()): ?> featured is-sticky<?php endif; ?>    <?php echo $post->getPostFormat() ?>">
                    <?php $count++;if($count%3==0){?>
                        <img src="<?php echo {you image url}?>" />
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPostRenderer($post)->toHtml() ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList($('post-list'));</script>
    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```